# tmux or weechat not updating screen

Tags: tmux, raspbian, weechat

I'm running weechat(1.0.1) in a tmux(1.6) session on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian[Linux 3.12.28+ armv6l GNU/Linux]). One of these two breaks screen updates. When running weechat by itself it works fine and no other software that I have found suffer from this issue. Nano for example works fine within tmux.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or resizing of terminal seems to refresh the screen once.

I have no clue what causes this or where to start debugging.

I've tried purging and reinstalling both programs as well as completely removing the settings files from them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apearantly i had `export TERM=xterm-256color` in my bashrc file.
Changing this to `export TERM=screen-256color-bce` solved it.

Apearantly weechat doesn't like xterm.